# Basic & Digest Negotiation Authentication

Tags: c#, webdav, http-authentication

I'm writing a WebDav implementation. I have implemented both basic and digest authentication.

My problem is that Digest Authentication isn't implemented by all clients. (In particular Dreamweaver) 
While Windows Web Folders doesn't work when sent a basic http challenge.

Is it possible to do client/server negotiation (Http Negotiation/SPNEGO)?
What would the headers look like?

Answer (score 0):

The web folders dialogue is often broken on Windows (do not know by which update, but it affects certain WinXp constellations and both Vista and 7)

The `net use * http://my-webdav-resource/` command line does mostly work in my experience, even when the wizard won't connect. But to use Basic-Auth on plain HTTP you will need to change the registry as described above for Vista/7.